# Issue with PHP Script with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

My code was working and I don't see issues with it. I tested all the MySQL statements in SQL and everything is fine there.

Everytime it fetches the password variable now it only returns Bad Password as if m_Pass is empty.

Anyone see anything wrong with those statements I don't?

I am using this as a one time password file transfer tool that you have to specify the filename and the password for accessing it.

Then it checks the SQL Database that contains the following format:

### id   |   m_File   |    m_Pass

0    |  Test.txt  |  testpass

Any help would be appreciated.

Index.php:

```
<?php
echo <<<EOF
    <form method="post" action="Index.php">
    File:<input type="text" name="txtFilename"><br>
    Password:<input type="text" name="txtPassword">
    <input type="submit" value="Download" name="submit">
    </form>
EOF;

function doProcess()
{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "<username>";
    $password = "<Password>";
    $dbname = "<dbname>";
    $filename = $_POST["txtFilename"];
    $pass = $_POST["txtPassword"];

    echo $filename . "<br>";
    if ($filename = ""){
        return;
    }
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    echo "Connected successfully" . "<br>";
    $sql = "SELECT id, m_Pass FROM Main WHERE m_File = '$filename'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $m_id = $row["id"];
    echo $m_id . "<br>";
    if ($row["m_Pass"] == $pass){
        echo "Downloading.<br>";
        //Download File
        $filename = utf8_decode("<Path>" . $filename);
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;    filename='.basename($filename));
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($filename);
            $sql = "delete from Main where id = '$m_id'"; 
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
    } else {
        echo $pass . " | '" . $row["m_Pass"] . "'<br>";
        echo "Bad Password.<br>";
    }
    echo "Done.<br>";
    // Close connection
    $conn->close();
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    doProcess();
} 
?>
```

Comment: SQL Injection alert.

Comment: *"My code was working"* - what changed since it did work?

Comment: Best way to debug this that I can think of is to (on a test copy that the wider internet can't reach) echo $row["m_Pass"] and $pass, and see what exactly is being compared.

Comment: TheChafing I did try that and its showing the correct $pass but not $row["m_Pass"]. It is almost like SQL is not returning anything even though its being passed the right info. I had also checked the filename as well.

Answer (score 0):

Got it... Turns out the SQL query command wasnt appending the $filename because of the block:

```
if ($filename = ""){
    return;
}
```

And I see why... I am assigning the value not comparing lol.